# Modifying solrconfig.xml from SolrJ?

Tags: solr, solrj, solrconfig

I want to modify the solrconfig.xml file from my java code.
If there is any source which gives examples of implementation of abstract SolrRequest in SolrJ for modifying solrconfig.xml, could you please point me out to them.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can't modify `solrconfig.xml` directly from the API, but you can [use the Config API](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/config-api.html#config-api) to modify configuration without having to edit `solrconfig.xml`.

The Config API creates an "overlay" that is used on top of the settings defined in solrconfig, and allows you to manipulate most  aspects that is contained in the config file.

You can see how to [manually build JSON and set it with SolrJ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5623307/solrj-disable-autocommit). I'm not sure if there's been anything added to SolrJ to abstract this away, but open tickets on the issue tracker indicate that it hasn't happened yet. It would also depend on which version of SolrJ you're using.

Comment: I am using SolrJ 7.2.1

Comment: Also I tried creating the JSON, there seems to be no 'setContentStreams' method with the GenericSolrRequest. Is there an alternative?

Answer (score 0):

As @MatsLindh said, you can use  [Config API](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_6/config-api.html#config-api) to update solr configs. 
You do not need to reload the collection either.

You can find command properties for config API [here](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_6/config-api.html#commands-for-common-properties)

Below is code for the newer version of Solr (>7.0), that updates property `updateHandler.autoSoftCommit.maxTime`:

```
//setting softCommit maxTime to 15000
final String command = "{\"set-property\":{\"updateHandler.autoSoftCommit.maxTime\":15000}}";

//path and method of request
final GenericSolrRequest rq = new GenericSolrRequest(SolrRequest.METHOD.POST, "/config", null);

// request string and request type
final ContentWriter content = new StringPayloadContentWriter(command, "application/json");

rq.setContentWriter(content);

//create your solrClient using zookeeper connection string
rq.process(solrClient, "<your collection name>");
```

You can find equivalent curl command [here](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_4/config-api.html#examples-of-common-properties)