# Need help, Few functions deprecated in SolrRequest?

Tags: solr, solrj

I was referring the below link.

Link -> [SolrJ: Disable Autocommit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5623307/solrj-disable-autocommit)

And found that for GenericSolrRequest, the method 'setContentStreams' is no longer supported.
Is there any other alternative.

I am using Solr 7.2.1 and SolrJ 7.2.1

Kindly Help !!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this set of commands:

```
String command = "{\"set-property\": {\"updateHandler.autoSoftCommit.maxTime\": 30000}}"; 
GenericSolrRequest rq = new GenericSolrRequest(SolrRequest.METHOD.POST, "/config", null); 
ContentStream content = new ContentStreamBase.StringStream(command); 
rq.setContentWriter(new RequestWriter.StringPayloadContentWriter(command,"application/json")); 
rq.process(cloudSolrClient,cloudSolrServerProduct.getDefaultCollection());
```